# How to Convert Image URL to File in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I faced this problem in my project, and I need to pass image as a file Image's get from URL(Example: Image URL [this](https://cnet4.cbsistatic.com/img/QJcTT2ab-sYWwOGrxJc0MXSt3UI=/2011/10/27/a66dfbb7-fdc7-11e2-8c7c-d4ae52e62bcc/android-wallpaper5_2560x1600_1.jpg) url needs to convert into a file without download a image), mean image URL need to convert a file then it passed to the server.Analysized but I'm not getting any answer,

```
{
            "templateName": "e. Before-After(1).png",
            "templateId": "",
            "templateUrl": "https://cnet4.cbsistatic.com/img/QJcTT2ab-sYWwOGrxJc0MXSt3UI=/2011/10/27/a66dfbb7-fdc7-11e2-8c7c-d4ae52e62bcc/android-wallpaper5_2560x1600_1.jpg"
        }
```

From this response "templateUrl" need to convert file

Comment: you need to download image first then after only you can convert it into file

Comment: Can you please add code

Comment: new File(uri.getPath());

Comment: @ND1010_, Buddy i'm not get image from mobile, i'm getting from URL,need to convert url image to File

Comment: @ Hi I'm Frogatto, No need to download ,which is load in image view then user press button then pass image as  a file

Comment: @TomC Do you want to _upload_ the loaded image in an `ImageView` to an external server?

Comment: the file can only be stored in file system, so you will have to download the image to be able to save the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{ 
@Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

            String imageURL = URL[0];

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                // Download Image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            File file = CommonUtils.getDownloadFile(placeHolder);

            if (file == null)
                return;

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

               // here you can get file in "file" variable.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    // Function for create a file where file download.
     public static File getDownloadFile(String placeHolder) {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/proManager");

            if (!myDir.exists()) {
                if (!myDir.mkdirs()) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            String fname = FILE_NAME_PRE_TEXT + placeHolder + ".jpg";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);

            if (file.exists()) file.delete();

            return file;
        }
```

How to Use this class

```
ImageDownloaderTask imageDownloaderTask = new ImageDownloaderTask();
  imageDownloaderTask.execute(url);
```